# clojurescript: consuming xml?

Tags: xml, clojure, clojurescript

My Clojurescript app needs to deal with an XML-based API. I know that there are mostly transparent remoting solutions like [fetch](https://github.com/ibdknox/fetch), but they seem to require that both ends be written in Clojure (i.e. fetch seems to be a noir/clojurescript solution).

What is "the right way" to consume an XML API using Clojurescript?

I'd just settle for being able to translate a XML fragment into a nested Clojure data structure (nested vectors), Hiccup-style, but a good processing API would be appreciated (something like C2's `unify` maybe?)

Comment: Nowadays [data.xml](https://github.com/clojure/data.xml) should also work in ClojureScript.

Comment: @gits The OP (Alex Miller) is actually a contributor to that library ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried the Google Closure library for that?

*edit* Google Closure library has moved to github. https://github.com/google/closure-library

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old question, but for folks that land here searching for it (like me). You can try to use the [Tubax](https://github.com/funcool/tubax) library.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend porting over one of the clojure XML libraries to clojurescript to do this